# Azure service works for batch request but not for Request - Response

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ml-studio

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

Hi,

I am new to Azure WebServices,
In the dev environment, my scripts are getting executed and I could even see the results in the Output.log , while I deploy it, it gives me error , which i have attached.

I have a slight hint that for single request response as.character() and as.interger() or as.numeric() in R are not working and thus generating the error or i might be wrong completely.

Comment: This error got resolved. The AzureML studio works in a tricky way. At one point in code i was writing as.data.frame(somedataframe) . Although this works fine but for unit request and response this line was now working. "Donot use/convert to as.data.frame() when working for single request response" is the learning.